# Proving equality between tensor product of generated sigma algebra and sigma algebra generated by the product of "countable base" of their sets

Tags: measure-theory

> For $n \in \mathbb{N_*}$, Let's say $(\Omega_i)_{1\leq i \leq n}$ are non empty sets. We have $(\mathcal{E}_i)_i$ non empty sets of subsets of $\Omega_i$ such as $\exists (H^k_i)_k\in \mathcal{E}_i^\mathbb{N} / \cup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}H^k_i=\Omega_i$. Prove that $$\otimes_{1\leq i \leq n} \sigma(\mathcal{E}_i) = \sigma(\Pi_{1\leq i \leq n}\mathcal{E}_i)$$

It is obvious that
$\sigma(\Pi_{1\leq i \leq n}\mathcal{E}_i) \subset \otimes_{1\leq i \leq n} \sigma(\mathcal{E}_i)$ but I don't know how to do the other inclusion.

Comment: the body of the question doesn't have the assumption that each $\mathcal{E}_i$ is countable

Comment: @Masacroso I don't know if I can call $\mathcal{E_i}$ a countable base of $\Omega_i$ However, it is not stated if $\mathcal{E_i}$ is countable or not